# Was I supposed to see a new privilege banner?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, beta-phase, privileges

I recently passed [750 rep](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/224/kristo) in the Board and Card Games beta.  According to the [privileges](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges) page, I gained the ability to view vote counts (which I did, btw).  But I never saw a banner indicating I had gained the privilege.  It's been a couple of days, so I thought it should have updated by now.  Is this a bug?

I already have that privilege on SO.  Is that why I wasn't notified on BCG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, veteran users (with the account association bonus) are flagged and receive fewer notifications of this sort.