# Do we get meta privilege notifications in the inbox?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

I know that we have the global inbox now that includes notifications to replace the banner we used to get.  But should it include the notifications from meta when we get a new privilege?

For example, my rep went over 500 which gave me the privilege to `create tags` and `retag questions` but I did not get my notification.

Should it appear in global notifications? Or is there a reason this is excluded?

<sub>* I was sad that I did not get my notification.</sub>

Comment: Yes, come to think of it I also recently passed 500 and did not get a notification.

Comment: Pretty sure you only get those notifications once, IE if your SO account already has a priv, your Meta/ect accounts won't get the same notification

Comment: You are correct @BenBrocka. I've linked to Jeff's post of that rule (although it doesn't explicity specify *once*) in my answer

Comment: You may want to clarify your post. The answer below is about MSO, which behaves like a full-blown site. Your post is a bit ambiguous, but it reads more like it's talking about ordinary per-site metas.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are notifications for Meta privileges

[image: image description]

However, you [won't always get notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71297/167443) for every privilege you earn.