# Spoilt "new privilege" party

Tags: support, privileges

I was approaching 20k at Stack Overflow. Invited my friends, family, some of my close colleagues. Got wine and beer. Invited a promising new band. The local radio station was all-set for an interview. An airplane was warming up to write the words "Trusted User" in the sky. We all waited for a random user somewhere in the world to pull the trigger and shoot me across the 20k line and make the glorious "new privilege" banner appear on the screen.

The banner never came.

I silently crossed 20k and that was it. Sent everybody home and drank the wine and beer myself.

Did I miss something? Or [could I have known better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71251/168269)? (The answer doesn't give much detail).

Comment: +1 for making me smile but I fear this is very much by design. (the banner you mention is looong gone, most we can hope for these modern days is such thing to appear as achievement :))

Comment: [Congratulations!!!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/election-celebration.jpg). Here is your complimentary [unicorn spending money](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/one-million-unicorn-bill-both-small.jpg).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That would be really cutting edge.

Comment: Let me try something...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [table here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/152859), the "trusted user" privilege should notify even veteran users.

This means, you should have seen this icon on top in bright green:

[image]

Clicking it should show you the privilege you just earned.

No bells and rings, but it should be there :).

For example, here's a privilege I was notified about:

> [image]

Comment: [Not a puppet](http://img0.etsystatic.com/000/0/5456598/il_fullxfull.54862952.jpg?ref=l2) at all... ;)

Comment: It's there! It's there! Drowned in an endless list of rep changes (ugh).

Comment: @Lix shadow, not puppet! And yes, it's still working... new privileges were showing up just now as result of passing 10 rep. :-)

Comment: @GertArnold cheers, you can throw a new party now!

Comment: @Kees I'm too used to Chrome with its built in spell check... this sock lives only in IE so such typo's are likely to happen. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ShadowoftheShadow - I'll admit I was looking for typos to earn some hats :P

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker yeah, "A Link to the Past" - nice hat! Oops, not this one. So you're after Florence Nightingale?

Comment: The Florence Nightingale indeed, but I need to scout around some more :P